# Adding a set accessor to a property in a class that derives from an abstract class with only a get accessor

Tags: c#, interface, properties, abstract-class

I have an abstract class, **AbsClass** that implements an interface, **IClass**. **IClass** has a couple properties with only Get accessors. **AbsClass** implements the properties of **IClass** as abstract properties to be defined in the classes that derive from **AbsClass**.

So all of the classes that derive from **AbsClass** will also need to satisfy **IClass** by having the same properties with Get accessors. However, in some cases I want to be able to add set accessors to the properties from **IClass**. Yet if I try to override the abstract properties in **AbsClass** with a set accessor I get this error

*ConcClassA.Bottom.Set cannot override because AbsClass.Bottom does not have an overridable set accessor*

See **ConcClassA** below.

If I have a class that is only implementing the **IClass** interface, but not inheriting from AbsClass then I am able to add a set accessor with out problems. See **ConcClassB**  below.

I could just implement IClass at each derivation of AbsClass rather then directly for AbsClass. Yet I know from my design that every AbsClass needs to also be an IClass so I'd rather specify that higher up in the hierarchy.

```
public interface IClass
{
    double Top
    {
        get;
    }
    double Bottom
    {
        get;
    }
}

abstract class AbsClass:IClass
{
    public abstract double Top
    {
        get;
    }

    public abstract double Bottom
    {
        get;
    }
}



class ConcClassA : AbsClass
{
    public override double Top
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public override double Bottom
    {
        get { return 1; }

        //adding a Set accessor causes error:
        //ConcClassA.Bottom.Set cannot override because AbsClass.Bottom does not have an overridable set accessor

        //set { }
    }

}

class ConcClassB : IClass
{
    public double Top
    {
        get { return 1; }
        //added a set accessor to an interface does not cause problem
        set { }
    }
    public double Bottom
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

So I think this will make more sense if I explain exactly what I'm trying to do rather then using the abstract example. I work for an Architecture firm and these are business objects related to an architectural design project.

I have an abstract class **RhNodeBuilding** that represents one type of building on a project. There is some general functionality, like the ability to have floors, that is defined in **RhNodeBuilding**. **RhNodeBuilding** also inherits from another abstract classes that allow it be part of a larger project tree structure.

**RhNodeBuilding** implements from an interface **IBuilding** which defines a number of read only properties that all buildings should be able to provide such as **TopElevation**, **BottomElevation**, **Height**, **NumberOfFloors**, etc..etc.. Keep in mind there are other building types that do not derive from **RhNodeBuilding**, but still need to implement **IBuilding**.

Right now I have two types that derive from **RhNodeBuilding**: **MassBuilding** and **FootPrintBuilding**. **MassBuilding** is defined by a 3D shape created by the user. That shape has a **TopElevation** and a **BottomElevation** that should be accessible through the corresponding properties, but you shouldn't be able to edit the 3D volume by changing the properties.

**FootPrintBuilding** on the other hand is defined by a closed curve and a height range to extrude that curve through. So not only should the class be able to return what the current elevations are but these elevations should also be able to be changed to redefine the height range.

So in summary. All buildings (**IBuildings**) need to be able to return a **TopElevation** and **BottomElevation**, but not all buildings should allow **TopElevation** or **BottomElevation** to be set directly. All **RhNodeBuildings** are **IBuildings**, and classes that derive from **RhNodeBuilding** may or may not need to be able to directly set **TopElevation** and **BottomElevation**.

```
public interface IBuilding
{
    double Top
    {
        get;
    }
    double Bottom
    {
        get;
    }
}

abstract class RhNodeBuilding:IBuilding
{
    public abstract double Top
    {
        get;
    }

    public abstract double Bottom
    {
        get;
    }
}



class MassBuilding: AbsClass
{

   //mass building only returns Top and Bottom properties so it works fine
    public override double Bottom
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

    public override double Top
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }

}


class FootPrintBuilding: AbsClass
{
    //Top and Bottom of FootPrintBuilding can both be retrieved and set
    public override double Top
    {
        get { return 1; }
        //adding a Set accessor causes error:
        //cannot override because RhNodeBuilding.Top does not have an overridable set accessor

        //set { }
    }

    public override double Bottom
    {
        get { return 1; }

        //adding a Set accessor causes error:
        //cannot override because RhNodeBuilding.Bottom does not have an overridable set accessor

        //set { }
    }

}
```

Right now it seems like the best option is to not have **RhNodeBuilding** implement **IBuilding**, but rather have every class that derives from **RhNodeBuilding** implement IBuilding. That way I can define the properties from **IBuilding** directly rather then as overrides.

```
abstract class AltRhNodeBuilding
{
    public abstract double Top
    {
        get;
    }
}


class AltFootPrintBuilding: IClass
{
    public override double Top
    {
        get { return 1; }

       //Can't add set access to overridden abstract property
        set { }
    }

    //No problem adding set accessor to interface property
    public double Bottom
    {
        get { return 1; }
        set {  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you breaking the interface "contract" by saying "this property is sometimes read-only but sometimes not"? Perhaps you need to break apart your interface (to another interface, for example) to allow for those classes that need read-only and others that need read/write.

Comment: Lack of property accessor doesn't imply that property is read-only for everyone (i.e. that it is immutable, and its value never changes) - it only implies that the property is read-only for client that uses this particular interface. So, no, it's not a breaking contract change. It's just a C#/CLR limitation.

Comment: Agreed, interface contracts only specify what you have to implement, not what you don't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works the way it does because properties aren't truly virtual - their accessor methods are. Thus, you cannot override `set` if there wasn't one in the base class.

What you can do is override *and shadow* the base class implementation, and provide your own new read/write properties. I don't know of any way to do this without introducing an additional class in the hierarchy:

```
class AbsClassB : AbsClass
{
    public override double Top { get { return ((ConcClassB)this).Top } }
    public override double Bottom { get { return ((ConcClassB)this).Bottom } }
}


class ConcClassB :  AbsClassB
{
    new public double Top
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    new public double Bottom
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

A better idea would be to define a protected virtual method right in `AbsClass`, and implement `Top.get` and `Bottom.get` in terms of that method. Then you can override that method directly in `ConcClassB`, and shadow the properties, without the need for an extra class:

```
abstract class AbsClass : IClass
{
    public double Top
    {
        get { return GetTop(); }
    }

    public double Bottom
    {
        get { return GetBottom(); }
    }

    protected abstract double GetTop();

    protected abstract double GetBottom();
}

class ConcClassB :  AbsClass
{
    new public double Top
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    new public double Bottom
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    protected override double GetTop()
    {
        return Top;
    }

    protected override double GetBottom()
    {
        return Bottom;
    }
}
```

Comment: But ConcClassB needs to derive from AbsClass

Comment: add you should always use an abstract definition (that is declare you're variables of an interface or similiar) extending the interface is a smell. you end up with either having to declare you arguments/variables of a concrete class -> bad idea if it can be avoided as it can in this case or you need to declare of the abstract type cst to the concrete type to get hold of the new operation. equally bad since you'd be violating liskov. Restricting the operations iis acceptable as is done with E.g. List<T> that implements IList (no T) but "hides" (explicit implementation) the none typed methods

Comment: Yup, my fault - misread the question. See the updated version.

Comment: I think I like the second idea of using the protected virtual method rather then creating an extra class. Could you show me a quick example of this I'm not sure what you mean exactly? Also I could always just have a set method the abstract property of the abstract class and then in the derived classes if the property is read only just not do anything in the set accessor of that property.

Comment: Added example. As for making property read/write in abstract class - you can, of course, but if it truly isn't writable for some of your classes, then you effectively lie to your clients about your contract.

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of curious as to why you would want these implementation classes to have public setter methods that are not part of the public interface.  It sounds to me like you may actually want these to be more restricted than public?

Other than that, I'm having a hard time thinking of a problem with this approach.  They would "hide" any properties from the superclass, but there are no property setters in the superclass anyway, so that seems ok.  It seems like it may be the simplest workaround.

Comment: I've added a less abstract explaination for what I'm doing to my question.

Comment: You still run into this error if you try to add a *private* setter to a property with an overridden getter.

Answer (score -12):

Use a global variable.