# Read-only interface without requiring body in abstract class?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract-class

I'd like to be able to create a read-only property in an interface that is writable in the instantiated class, but I'm having problems if the inheritance goes through an abstract class:

```
interface IFoo {
    string Foo { get; }
}

abstract class Bar : IFoo {
}

class Baz : Bar {
    public string Foo { get; private set; }
}
```

This gives me an error `Bar does not implement interface member IFoo.Foo`. Is there any way to circumvent this? I want the ultimately-instantiated class to determine the visibility of the setter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a set accessor to a property in a class that derives from an abstract class with only a get accessor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169571/adding-a-set-accessor-to-a-property-in-a-class-that-derives-from-an-abstract-cla)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement it abstract:

```
abstract class Bar : IFoo
{
    public abstract string Foo { get; }
}
```

However, it doesn't look like when you do this that you can choose to override the visibility in the Baz class.

The best you can do is to use a backing field in the derived class:

```
class Baz : Bar
{
    private string _foo;
    public override string Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
    }
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169599/545680) on a duplicate question goes into more detail on the why. The problem stems from the fact that property getters and setters are abstract, rather than the property itself.